# Extend trial period of a software

Tags: trialware

I am curious as to how some applications know if my trial period is over. Even if I uninstall the software, and reinstall it, how can the software know if my trial period is over ? Simple tricks like changing the date and time are futile.

The question is simple. What are the possible ways for an application to know that ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are registry values written in the windows registry Including the dates for installation and other details. Am not sure what you want to do but mostly this is what they do. Even after you uninstall the software, the registry values for the application are left in the registry.

So to answer your question: The Application uses the registry entries to know that your trial period has expired even after you remove the software and try ti re-install.

Comment: Why are You Capitalizing random Words throughout Your Sentence?

Comment: Yeah looking up the registry is an option as I had already guessed. Is there any particular key value pair that I should look for in the registry ? But I guess it'll vary from application to application.

Comment: It will vary from application to application but you can always search through the registry using keywords.